# Using T-SQL to produce distinct elements/rows for output to XML

Tags: sql-server, xml, excel

I am having issues with getting SQL server to produce the type of XML file I am looking for. I have a very basic query, that will end up generating 53 rows. In turn I need to uniquely map each row in different areas of an excel spreadsheet.

```
Select ID, Value
From Table
FOR XML Path
```

This creates XML

```
<Row>
   <Id> 1 </Id>
   <Value> X </Value>
</Row>
<Row>
   <Id> 2 </Id>
   <Value>Y </Value>
</Row>
```

With a schema

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="row">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="ID" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element name="Value" type="xs:decimal" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

This produces a schema and XML file that get the data I need but I cannot map each row distinctly. For this project I can change anything except for the fact that I need SQL to produce the schema and XML itself, instead of writing it myself like I have done in the past.

Ideally I would be looking for a XML file that looked like this

```
 <Row1>
       <Id> 1 </Id>
       <Value> X </Value>
 </Row1>
 <Row2>
       <Id> 2 </Id>
       <Value>Y </Value>
 </Row2>
```

With an ideal schema

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="row1">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="ID" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element name="Value" type="xs:decimal" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="row2">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="ID" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element name="Value" type="xs:decimal" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I have tried the other XML routes as well (auto/raw/explicit) but it did not  work either. Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide sample data and expected output?   As it stands, your question is not very clear.

Comment: I added what it produces and what I am aiming to create

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my issue, I thought I would post it just to help anyone else.

I used a dynamic pivot to move each distinct row into a separate column that only had the one value.

First I added the number 1 to the beginning of my select statement so that on the future pivot, each answer would share the same first element

```
Select 1, 'ColumnName', 'Value'
INTO DBO.db.Table1
FROM Table 


DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(MAX) 
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX) 



SELECT  @cols = STUFF(( SELECT DISTINCT TOP 100 PERCENT 
                                '],[' + t.ColumnName 
                        FROM   Dbo.Db.Table1 AS t 
                        --ORDER BY '],[' + t.ID 
                        FOR XML PATH('') 
                      ), 1, 2, '') + ']' 

--SELECT  @cols

SET @query = N'SELECT ID,'+ @cols +'
INTO dbo.db.PivotTable
FROM
(SELECT t1.iD, t1.ColumnName, t1.Value 
FROM db.dbo.Table1 AS t1) p 
PIVOT (MAX([Value]) FOR ColumnName IN ( '+ @cols +' )) 
AS pvt;' 

EXEC (@query)


Select * into #Temp FROM db.dbo.PivotTable

select * from #TEMP
FOR XML AUTO, ROOT('Root1D')

DROP TABLE #Temp
```

I was then able to create a schema file, load it into an excel document and then map each single element wherever I wanted. After that I just imported the XML file that the above procedure generated, and it worked perfectly.